# How can I run a coroutine in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

My webscraper takes about 10 mins to run, I am trying to use the threading library to allow my webscraper to run in the background after data has been returned to whomever made a call to my API I created with Flask.

My code looks something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)


class Compute(Thread):
    def __init__(self, request):
        print("init")
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.request = request

    def run(self):
        print("RUN")
        command = './webscrape.py -us "{user}" -p "{password}" -url "{url}"'.format(**self.request.json)
        output = subprocess.call(['bash','-c', command])


@application.route('/scraper/run', methods=['POST'])
def init_scrape():
    thread_a = Compute(request.__copy__())
    thread_a.start()
    return jsonify({'Scraping this site: ': request.json["url"]}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
     application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8080")
```

Now I am testing my API with postman and when I make a POST request it prints out "init" but dosen't seem to go any further to start the `run()` function, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling thread_a.run(), yoju are just initiating it and calling .start() (Which I assume is a method from Thread class?

Comment: Yeah thats right